# How can I create an airplane radar using python graphics? (draw)

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

```
from graphics import*

def main():

    win = GraphWin("My Window",500,500)
    win.setBackground(color_rgb(0,0,0)) 

#Point 
    pt = Point(250,250)
    pt.setOutline(color_rgb(255,255,0))
    pt.draw(win) 


    win.getMouse()
    win.close() 

main()
```

How can I make the lines, the circle, and erase the background color so the result looks like the illustration?

[image: Radar image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What exactly do you want to achieve? A complex picture like the one you shared? An animation?

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes, I intend to do something similar to the image, the project is with animations but I wanted to learn to do just the drawing, I can't find sources to learn how to use python graphics.

Comment: you should find some information if you will search `graphics.py` instead of `graphics`. OR even better search `python graphics.py`. ie. doc [Graphics](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html)

Comment: BTW: you could also open file `graphics.py` to see source code - and you will see what classes and functions you can use. [source code](http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Zelle%27s_Graphics.py_for_Python_3).

Comment: BTW: `graphics.py` is built on top of `tkinter` and you may have to learn also `tkinter` to use some functions which are not described in `graphics` but they are available - like `tkinter.after(milliseconds, function_name)` to run some function periodically and make animation.

Answer (score 1):

This module is known also as `graphics.py` or `Zelle's graphics` and you should use these names to search more information.

[Home Page for graphics.py](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/index.html) with [documentation](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/index.html) and [examples](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/ppics3/code/)

[Hands-on Python Tutorial > Graphics](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html)

---

You could also check [source code](http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Zelle%27s_Graphics.py_for_Python_3) to see all classes and functions.

---

This module is built on top of `tkinter` so you may have to learn also `tkinter` for some functions which are not available directly in `graphics.py` but you still can use it.

For example `tkinter` has `after(milliseconds, function_name)` to execute function with delay or repeate the same function after delay - so you can use it to create animation.

**BTW:** in `after()` has to be function's name without `()` and without arguments - and later `tkinter` will use `()` to execute it. It is called `callback`.

---

Example which uses `after()` to move point. This way it animates element and you still can click window to close program.

```
from graphics import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred 
import random

# --- functions ---

def move():
    dx = random.randint(-10, 10)
    dy = random.randint(-10, 10)
    pt.move(dx, dy)
    # move again after 100ms (0.1s)
    win.after(100, move)

# --- main ---

win = GraphWin("My Window",500,500)
win.setBackground(color_rgb(0,0,0))

pt = Point(250, 250)
pt.setOutline(color_rgb(255,255,0))
pt.draw(win)

# move first time after 100ms (0.1s)
win.after(100, move)

#win.mainloop()
win.getMouse()

win.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** after digging in information I created version without `after()`

```
from graphics import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred 
import random
import time

# --- main ---

win = GraphWin("My Window",500,500)
win.setBackground(color_rgb(0,0,0))

pt = Point(250, 250)
pt.setOutline(color_rgb(255,255,0))
pt.draw(win)

while True:
    if win.checkMouse():
        break
    dx = random.randint(-10, 10)
    dy = random.randint(-10, 10)
    pt.move(dx, dy)
    time.sleep(0.1)

win.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this will help me a lot in the project in the future. For now I am trying to learn how to draw radar (circles, lines), in the future I will give animation.

Comment: BTW: on Stackoverflow questions for `graphics` use tag [zelle-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zelle-graphics)